# Random button that reload a div or script not page using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I'm really new at this and I need a random button on my page that would show a new line of information in a div every time someone click on the random button. I was also wondering if there is over 800 lines is it possible to put it in an outside file as txt or html.

Here is what I got so far and well it doesn't work and I'm getting confuse... Please help

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#text').hide();

        $('a#random').click(function(){
            $('#text').toggle();
        })

        function RndText() {
            var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
            document.getElementById('#text').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
        }
        var textarray = [
         "Hello",
         "How are you",
         "Good Bye"    
        ];
        $("#text").load()
    })
</script>

<body>
    <div id="text">Line to Show</div>
    <a href="#" id="random">RANDOM</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Javascript by itself does not have the ability to create files. You'll need to either find a service or create a service that will let you make files. Then you'll have to post all the data to that service.

Comment: Thanks, so I would need to include every line in my textarray for them to show up I assume

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwexjdj2/

Comment: In the RndText function,  the instruction document.getElementById('#text').innerHTML=textarray[rannum]; doesn't refresh the text. You can replace it by $('#text').html(textarray[rannum]);

Answer (score 1):

Uh.  Pretty much this:

```
$('a#random').click(function(){
    $('#text').toggle();
    RndText();  //you're good
});
```

Although I will point out that `RndText()` uses `document.getElementById` when it could use `$("#text")` instead. (there's a [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method that will write the value instead of the `.innerHTML` property).

`document.getElementById` is also not currently working because you used "#text" instead of "text", jQuery uses CSS selectors, getElementById does not.

Answer (score 0):

Add execution of `RndText` when you clicks on Random button.

```
$('a#random').click(function(){
  $('#text').show();
  RndText();
})
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKS!!!!! This is so cool! Thank you so much I've been trying to do this for so many hours

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a button and you can run this code by clicking the button below. However, I did not quite understand you second part of the question:  800 lines in separate file, what do you wanna do with it? Tell me so that I can helo you further...

### Editted:

```html
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('demo.txt');
$lines= split("\n",$data);
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var textarray = <?php echo json_encode($lines); ?>;

 function RndText() {
     var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
     $('#text').text(textarray[rannum]);
     console.log(textarray[rannum]+"  "+rannum+" "+textarray.length);
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#text').hide();

  $('#random').click(function(){
      $('#text').show();
      RndText();
  });
 });

</script>

<body>

<div id="text"></div>
<button id="random">RANDOM</button>

</body>
```

Comment: The textarray would have over 800 lines of random, so I was wondering if there is any way to put all those lines in another document to make it easier  to not have to put it in the script directly

Comment: You have to use PHP or some other javascript library which will provide you the data from the file. Also know that using PHP or such JS library might require web server to the code. This is because the browser restricts any website from making changes to end users files or reading any data from users computer. So basucally, browser does not allow any kind of read or write operation using JS for security of user. Let me  know if you would like to know that code. Believe me,It will be pretty simple.

Comment: I've tried setting up my website with a testing server and I kept on getting a error message, but when the site is up and running it could be a good idea to switch to PHP instead, I could try to use your code if you don't mind

Comment: @MelissaBerry check out the updated code. That should do the trick. Make sure Demo.txt file is in the same directory. You can put as much content as you want in the text file.  Let me know if you wanna know how it  works...  !!! Cheers !!! :D